# Do we need optax.scale(-1.0) if we use optax.chain() every time?

Tags: python, deep-learning, backpropagation, jax

In optax tutorial, There seem to be two versions of the example for using `optax.chain` and update rule.

1. In the [github tutorial](https://github.com/deepmind/optax/blob/master/examples/quick_start.ipynb), section Custom optimizers, it says:

> Scale updates by -1 since `optax.apply_updates` is additive and we want to descend on the loss.

```py
# Exponential decay of the learning rate.
scheduler = optax.exponential_decay(
    init_value=start_learning_rate, 
    transition_steps=1000,
    decay_rate=0.99)

# Combining gradient transforms using `optax.chain`.
gradient_transform = optax.chain(
    optax.clip_by_global_norm(1.0),  # Clip by the gradient by the global norm.
    optax.scale_by_adam(),  # Use the updates from adam.
    optax.scale_by_schedule(scheduler),  # Use the learning rate from the scheduler.
    # Scale updates by -1 since optax.apply_updates is additive and we want to descend on the loss.
    optax.scale(-1.0)
)
```

2. But in [opt-101](https://optax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/optax-101.html) it just uses adam without any sign flip.

```py
# Finally, we can fit our parametrized function using the Adam optimizer
# provided by optax.
optimizer = optax.adam(learning_rate=1e-2)
params = fit(initial_params, optimizer)
```

Or the next schedule example

```py
schedule = optax.warmup_cosine_decay_schedule(
  init_value=0.0,
  peak_value=1.0,
  warmup_steps=50,
  decay_steps=1_000,
  end_value=0.0,
)

optimizer = optax.chain(
  optax.clip(1.0),
  optax.adamw(learning_rate=schedule),
)

params = fit(initial_params, optimizer)
```

Question:

- Could you explain why the first example needs to be scaled by `-1.0`?
- Is this a valid operation?

---

By changing code snippet in [opt-101](https://optax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/optax-101.html)

```py
# Finally, we can fit our parametrized function using the Adam optimizer
# provided by optax.
optimizer = optax.adam(learning_rate=1e-2)
params = fit(initial_params, optimizer)
```

to this snippet

```py
optimizer = optax.chain(
    optax.adam(1e-4),
    optax.scale(-1.0)
)
params = fit(initial_params, optimizer)
```

The output does not converge.

```
step 0, loss: 8.13604736328125
step 100, loss: 8.20535945892334
step 200, loss: 9.430334091186523
step 300, loss: 10.792684555053711
step 400, loss: 9.76855754852295
step 500, loss: 9.106145858764648
step 600, loss: 13.101574897766113
step 700, loss: 11.097556114196777
step 800, loss: 5.794736385345459
step 900, loss: 11.414172172546387
```

---

P.S. I found a similar question on [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/deepmind/optax/discussions/445).

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the function you are trying to optimize and whether you want to minimize or maximize it. In both examples you shared, the loss functions are being minimized. In first example, the loss function is provided in the code, which is `Mean Squared Error`. This loss is always **non-negative**, hence its gradient will always point to the direction that maximizes it. Since the goal is minimize it, you have to multiply it by `-1.0`, i.e `optax.scale(-1.0)`.
In the second example, the loss function that is being used is `optax.sigmoid_binary_cross_entropy`. Let's take a look at the definition of this function from the official [code](https://github.com/deepmind/optax/blob/master/optax/_src/loss.py#L143#L175). Note I've removed the comments for brevity:

```
def sigmoid_binary_cross_entropy(logits, labels):
  chex.assert_type([logits], float)
  labels = labels.astype(logits.dtype)
  log_p = jax.nn.log_sigmoid(logits)
  # log(1 - sigmoid(x)) = log_sigmoid(-x), the latter more numerically stable
  log_not_p = jax.nn.log_sigmoid(-logits)
  return -labels * log_p - (1. - labels) * log_not_p
```

As you can see, this is just the **negative** log-likelihood function of the Bernoulli distribution (as they're doing binary classification in the example). Here the negative sign is already in the loss function, and the gradient of this function will always point to the direction that minimizes it. So you don't have to flip its direction to minimize it. In fact doing so will result in maximizing the loss, which is what's happening when you applied `optax.scale(-1.0)`

Comment: You mentioned that `scale(-1.0)` depends on the loss function. But in same GitHub tutorial section "Basic usage of Optax", it use same MSE loss. It seems that it doesn't match your answer.

Comment: It does match my answer, as mentioned in the first paragraph you have to use `scale(-1.0)` for MSE loss. This comment in the notebook also further explain is "Scale updates by -1 since optax.apply_updates is additive and we want to descend on the loss."

Answer (score 0):

The actual reason is that `optax.adam` (or `optax.adamw`) is simply a chain of `transform.scale_by_adam` and `transform.scale_by_learning_rate`

https://github.com/google-deepmind/optax/blob/main/optax/_src/alias.py#L307

and `transform.scale_by_learning_rate` does the sign flip for you if you check the the doc of this function "Scale by the (negative) learning rate (either as scalar or as schedule)"

https://github.com/google-deepmind/optax/blob/main/optax/_src/transform.py#L934C1-L940C1

so there is no need to call scale(-1) on optimizers like `adam` and `adamw`.